# Confusing Apple In App Purchase products

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, in-app-purchase

I am creating an note taking app like Evernote for iPad. I decided to provide some In App Purchase plans for 2 reasons.

1. Unlock more features in app.
2. Should be Auto renewable after specified time period.

Now i have confusion which type of In App Purchase to select for this. I am interested in *Auto-Renewable Subscriptions*

After visiting the guidlines [here](https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/In-App-Purchase-Guidelines.pdf), i found

> You may sell and unlock additional functionality within your
>   application using In-App Purchase. Adding additional functionality to
>   an app should generally be considered Non-Consumable.

But Non-consumable are not Auto-Renewable.

So which type of product should i choose?

Does Apple approve unlocking app features with Auto-Renewable Subscriptions?

Also, after purchasing a plan, on how many devices user can unlock(restore) features with same Apple ID?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Beware of using `Auto-Renewable subscription` becuase `Auto-Renewable subscription`'s world is very small. **99%** of the apps gets rejected in this case. Basically apple allows `Auto-Renewable subscription` for apps those follows:

- **Newspaper, Magazine**
- **News Stand**
- **audio/video streaming feeds**
- **membership to a dating service**
- **Business app providing cloud storage services**

you can read a well defined document (page 4) by apple here:

https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/In-App-Purchase-Guidelines.pdf

A application of mine got rejected with these comments by apple:

> We found that the Purchasability Type for one or more of your In-App
>   Purchase products was inappropriately set, which is not in compliance
>   with the App Store Review Guidelines.
>
> Cloud-books is set to Auto-Renew Subscription.
>
> Based on product functionality, it would be more appropriate to use
>   the non-renewing subscription In-App Purchase type. The Auto-Renewable
>   Subscription product is best suited for apps that require or feature
>   dynamically or frequently changing content, such as digital
>   periodicals or radio subscriptions.
>
> Non-renewing subscriptions can still be offered, but auto-renewable
>   subscriptions are now preferred for the following reasons

I have submitted app today with `non-auto subs` and see now they approves it or not, otherwise finally I would have to make if `consumable` with some server mechanism of forcing user to buy it again after a certain time period.

Go through this thread, might me useful for you:

[iOS recurring subscription policy for service, not content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6184902/ios-recurring-subscription-policy-for-service-not-content/)

and read this article also:

http://www.marco.org/2012/01/06/autorenewable-subscription-restrictions

**UPDATE:**
My another app on auto-renewable subscription got approved by apple. Before approval it got 2 rejections. First for insufficient content in IAP Product identifiers and second for insufficient application description.

Comment: @Vaibhav, thanks for reply. So you mean there is no way to Auto-renew purchases? So what is your suggestion according to my situation. Should i implement consumable products, with my server side restriction on content time period. Or i should implement non-auto subscriptions? Which is better in both?

Comment: they should approve `non-auto renewable` i think but I myself not sure about this until my submission gets some response from them.

Comment: @VaibhavSaran, i have seen Evernote is using Auto-renewable subscription, and it is working perfectly. So if my app approves too with Auto-renew subscription, i don't want my user to purchase subscription once and unlock it on many devices, unless he is logged in with same Application's email/password. Would Apple allow me to restrict user purchases on basis of my own web server's assigned IDs?

Comment: you mean to say to restrict multiple login at same time? Yes you can do this.