# App Store primary and se secondary category for auto renewing subscription

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

I develop an app which I put under primary category Health and Fitness on iTunesConnect but they reject my app because of autorenewing subscription(in-app purchases) by saying:

> Apps may only use auto-renewing subscriptions for periodicals (newspapers, magazines), business Apps (enterprise, productivity, professional creative, cloud storage), and media Apps (video, audio, voice), or the App will be rejected

So my question is can I set  primary category as Health and Fitness and secondary category as news-paper or magazine(any to which they allow auto renewing subscription) or vice versa to avoid rejection.  Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about AppStore approval, but is your app a newspaper or magazine?  It doesn't matter what category you put it in, it is what your app is/does that counts.

Comment: My app is not news paper or magazine but it's a meditation app which has some mp3 files for which we are using monthly subscription(in app purchase). For using Auto renewing subscription It matters in which category you put your app

Comment: I would have thought your subscription would have been covered by "media". The category doesn't matter. What matters is whether the Apple reviewer thinks you are using subscription appropriately. Putting your app in the newspaper category when it isn't a newspaper will just give another reason for rejection. It sounds like non-consumable purchase is a better match for what your app delivers.

Comment: Yes you are correct but we want to charge user monthly for using those mp3 files, so we thinking to put Primary category as Health and Fitness and Secondary category as Media or Business something which they allow us for auto renewing subscription, do you think will it work to put secondary category as Business or Media?

Comment: You can try but only Apple can say. I don't think the category will make a difference.

Comment: @Paulw11 Category is important for auto-renewing subscriptions for periodicals. Asad Amodi please check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21306475/1444321

Comment: This question/answer is 3 years old. The question you linked to is even older. Apple lets apps use subscriptions to unlock lots of different functionality now. Regardless, setting a category of "magazine" won't change Apple's mind if they think your app shouldn't be approved. They look at function, not the category.